# What dose the yellow in the new Microsoft logo represent?

Tags: colors

Microsoft just launched a new logo and from [this video](http://youtu.be/OzkZWvAJUr0) you can see that the different colors represent different parts of Microsoft. From the video you can clearly see that:

Blue = Windows
Green = Xbox
Orange = Office

Yellow = ?

Is it windows phone or what?

Comment: Yellow is for the return of [Microsoft BOB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Bob), Microsoft's new cross platform companion.

Comment: It’s definitely [not Windows Phone](http://nokiagadgets.com/2012/08/08/new-windows-phone-logo-revealed/). The only product that fits at this time is [Bing](http://www.bing.com/favicon.ico): [\[1\]](http://i.stack.imgur.com/bV8iZ.png) [\[2\]](http://i.stack.imgur.com/g9NXJ.png).

Comment: Yup, [definitely Bing](http://i.stack.imgur.com/tVCPt.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

I think the yellow is just because it's always been there, since the logo for Windows 3.1.  Every few years, they slighly reinterpret the logo, removing the black borders between the colours, and now straightening out the swoosh.  The rebranding campaign can't fully change the logo to something no one recognizes, so the colours were maintained.  The logo now also looks more like four "tiles" used in Windows 8 and Windows Phone.  Probably not a coincidence.

It just so happens they can make green into Xbox.  I'm sure that wasn't the intention in the 80s when the Windows logo was first made.

Maybe they do have something up their sleeve for what yellow means, but I think it can only be speculated.

Answer (score 1):

It maybe be related to the Windows Phone. From Wikipedia:

> Microsoft unveiled a new corporate logo at the opening of its 23rd
>   Microsoft store in Boston indicating the company's shift of focus from
>   the classic style to the tile-centric Metro interface which it uses on
>   the **Windows Phone** platform, **Xbox 360** and the upcoming **Windows 8** and
>   **Office** Suites.

Then again the next line says:

> The new logo also includes four squares with the colors
>   of the **then-current** Windows logo.

It's more like that they used the old logo and gave it new meaning.

Comment: *> It maybe be related to the Windows Phone.*   [Not likely.](http://nokiagadgets.com/2012/08/08/new-windows-phone-logo-revealed/)